# What's the limit of $\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1} $

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I've tried a lot in how to solve this limit, What's is the limit of
$$\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1} $$

Comment: Approach this with a geometric sum (or use polynomial division).

Comment: Hint: $x + 1$ divides $x^{101} + 1$. This is because $-1$ is a root of $x^{101} + 1$.

Comment: You can use l'hopital's rule to find  this limit

Comment: @user262291 why use l'hopital's rules when you literally have the definition of the derivative in front of you ?

Comment: You would end up with the same answer. He just asked for a way to evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with mercio (see the comments above) which seems to be the most elegant way. Put $f(x) = x^{101}$. Then $f'(x) = 101x^{100}$ and hence
$$
\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1} = \lim_{x\to -1}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x-(-1)} = f'(-1) = 101.
$$

Comment: What is the name of the rule applied to the limit?

Comment: It is the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{101}+1=(x+1)(x^{100}-x^{99}+x^{98}\cdots+x^2-x+1)$$
$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{100} (-1)^{2k}=101$$